# Find limit with integrals $\lim_{n\to \infty} n(\sqrt[n^2]{nI_n}-1)$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

> Given that
>
> $$I_n=\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{nx}(\tan^{n-1}x+\tan^nx+\tan^{n+1}x)dx,$$
>
> I have to find the limit
>
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n(\sqrt[n^2]{nI_n}-1)$$

I tried to use $0 < \text{tg} x < 1$ for $0<x<\pi/4$ and i found that 
$0<I_n < \frac{3}{n}\left(e^{n\pi/4}-1\right)$. I think with this, the limit should be $0$, but I don't know.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Interesting idea, but with $n\to \infty$ you have $e^{nx}/n \to \infty$ as well

Answer (score 4):

Split $I_n=I_1+I_2$, where:

$$I_1=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}e^{nx}(\tan^{n-1}x+\tan^{n+1}x)\,dx,\ \ \ I_2=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}e^{nx}(\tan^{n}x)\, dx$$

Now, integrating by parts:

$$\begin{aligned} I_1&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}e^{nx}\tan^{n-1}x (1+\tan^2x)\,dx\\
&= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}e^{nx}\tan^{n-1}x\cdot  (\tan x)'\,dx\\
&= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}e^{nx}\frac{1}{n}(\tan^n x)'\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{n}e^{nx}\tan^nx\bigg|_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} - \frac{1}{n}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}ne^{nx}(\tan^{n}x)\, dx\\
&=\frac{1}{n} e^{\frac{n\pi}{4}}-I_2
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus $I_n=\dfrac{1}{n} e^{\frac{n\pi}{4}}$, and the limit is:

$$\begin{aligned} \lim_{n\to \infty} n(\sqrt[n^2]{nI_n}-1) &= \lim_{n\to \infty}n(e^{\frac{\pi}{4n}}-1) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{4n}}-1}{\frac{\pi}{4n}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\end{aligned}$$